# Fixed element positioned relative to the viewport(left) and static element (right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Probably this is impossible but I had to try:
Let's imagine an element fixed to the viewport.

```
Position: fixed;  
Top: 30px;
Left: 0px;
```

But the right side relative to a certain element on the page (container) with `position: static` and that IS NOT FLOATING INSIDE THE FIXED ELEMENT. It is outside, independent, static somewhere in the page:[image]

I am aware that if I set the right position of the fixed element normally will be set relative to the right side of the viewport.

So, in this case, when resizing the browser the right side of the fixed element would not be relative to right side of the viewport but to the right side of the container.

Maybe some javaScript? jQuery?

Comment: Not enough code/details at the moment to settle on a solution - how is the container positioned relative to the right of the page? Have you tried tackling this problem yourself yet?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention. I will edit the question. The container is not fixed to the viewport. It has position: static. I tried but the most I can do is to fix the element (top/left/right) to the viewport.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but still... You can always capture an event when browser's size is changed. Then, if you need to have your (black) elements starting at a fixed position at the left and extending to a **calculated** position at the right (which would be relating to the **container**), you can get the position of the container + its width and then change the size of the (black) element to match your needs. Just an idea though...

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a very good idea indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you know beforehand where the right edge of the "container" will lie (based on its width/left offset), you can achieve the desired layout in most modern browsers using the CSS3 [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility). In pseudocode, your formula for `right` would look something like:

```
right: calc(100% - container_width - container_left_offset);
```

Here's a working demo of the code:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
#fixed {
  background: #CCC;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: calc(100% - 100px - 300px);
  top: 30px;
}
#static {
  background: #999;
  height: 800px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
  Fixed
</div>
<div id="static">
  Container
</div>
```

However, if the right edge position of the container cannot be known beforehand (eg. Dynamic width/variable content), you'll probably have to take a JavaScript route. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am going to try it out but it seems a wonderful solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @viery365 Great! Let me know if it ends up working for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This solved the problem!!! I wonder about dynamic content though and that could be just a responsive image (working as a container) without any size provided, only min-width or max-width. But this formula works very well for fixed width (even percentage). Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you wamt is something like this

[image]

That was achieved using pure css, the css file is called (in the example) style.css and this is its content

h1{color:red}

```
.fixed-div{
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:50px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 2em;
    border: 2px #789875 dotted 
}

.f_container{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin:-20px 0 0 0;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: #778854;
    border: 1px #946427 solid
}

.floating_text{float:left;}
```

as you can see its very simple, the fixed-div class controlls the behavior of the fixed div (no brainer here) I think the css requieres no further explanaition, however, if you need it I'll gladly provide it.

the floating container is being styled by the f_container class

as you can see this class is relative (to the fixed div) and is floating at its right side, this way, if the viewport ir resized making the fixed div width change (since its width is a % of the viewport size) the floating container will always be adapting to the change.

your question didn't specify if the floating div height is related to the viewport, but since it is the most interesting scenario (if its fixed you can simply set it) thats the one I'll cover here; as you can see, the css class contains:

```
height: 80vh;
```

vh is a viewport unit that represents a 1/100th of the viewports height

so, you could say

```
80vh=80% of the viewports height
```

Hope I understood your question and this answer was helpful

edit: forgot to add the html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fixed-div">
            <div class="f_container">
                this is your floating container
            </div>
            <p class="floating_text"> this is the fixed div</p>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you time spent to resolve this problem. My question probably was not very well written. I am so sorry for that! The container  is not floating inside the fixed element. It is outside somewhere in the page and it is static. There is another answer that solved the problem but I am still thinking about some javaScript that can deal with dynamic width. So, please read the other answer and if you can figure out I would be very pleased as other people seeing this question.

Comment: Doing it with js is relatively easy, however, if you don't mind, may I ask why would you prefer to do it via JS?  and, while I'm at it, why do you need them to be separate divs, are you looking for a specific behavior?

Comment: The accepted answer works perfectly with CSS. I just need javaScript if the width of the static container would be dynamic. I want separate divs because one is the nav and the other is the sidebar. The problem is solved though!:)